recover from cudaErrorMemoryAllocation
in my application we calls cudaMallocHost, the quantity of allocated memory depends on user's chooses, so it can happens that the allocation fails because went out of memory, when it happens the call returns cudaErrorMemoryAllocation, in this case we call cudaFreeHost that returns cudaErrorMemoryAllocation as well (because it may also return error codes from previous, asynchronous launches as documented).
My problem is that from now until the end of program any cudaMallocHost fails, even the littlest, did the cudaFreeHost fail? How can I recover from this situation?
EDIT:
Looks like it is not clear, let's say I am trying to allocate 10 buffer of 1Gb, it fails at 8th, with cudaErrorMemoryAllocation so I call cudaFreeHost for the first 7 and all of them return cudaErrorMemoryAllocation (?), then I try to allocate 512Kb, and it keeps fails.
Add code example:
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>

#define N_ALLOCATION 10
#define SIZE (size_t)2 * (size_t)1024 * (size_t)1024 * (size_t)1024

bool MyCheck(const cudaError_t &err)
{
    if(err == cudaSuccess) return true;
    std::cout << "Error " << err << std::endl;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    void* ptr[N_ALLOCATION] = {nullptr};
    for(int i = 0; i < N_ALLOCATION; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "allocation " << i << std::endl;
        if(!MyCheck(cudaMallocHost(&(ptr[i]), SIZE)))
            break;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N_ALLOCATION; ++i)
    {
        if(ptr[i])
        {
            std::cout << "free " << i << std::endl;
            if(MyCheck(cudaFreeHost(ptr[i])))
            {
                ptr[i] = nullptr;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "allocation after free" << std::endl;
    MyCheck(cudaMallocHost(&(ptr[0]), SIZE));

in my computer its output is:
allocation 0
allocation 1
allocation 2
allocation 3
allocation 4
allocation 5
allocation 6
allocation 7
Error 2
free 0
free 1
Error 2
free 2
Error 2
free 3
Error 2
free 4
Error 2
free 5
Error 2
free 6
Error 2
allocation after free
Error 2

Me expection is that the "allcation after free" and the frees do not return errors.

If the malloc call fails, it doesn’t allocate anything. Why would you call free in such a situation?

I'm guessing you are on (native, or WSL2) windows?  I can run a successful test on (native) linux, albeit somewhat different than yours, which shows a successful cudaMallocHost after a failed one.

Hi, I thought about it a lot, and I am going to think that is a driver bug... i am using CUDA 12.2.138

The cudaMallocHost and cudaFreeHost functions are marked __host__, they are not async. They are normal CPU bound functions.
If you call cudaMallocHost and get an allocation error, that error is due to the allocation and not some error from earlier async calls.
If the allocation fails, your pointer will not be valid, and thus you cannot call cudaFreeHost on it, because, well, it was never allocated.
If your allocation returns cudaErrorMemoryAllocation, then set the pointer to nullptr and if the pointer is null, then do not call cudaFreeHost.
Now all will be well.
There is no need to "recover" from a failed allocation, your system is not in an invalid state, because a failed allocation does not do anything. You just don't have that much memory available, make a smaller allocation, or free up some space.
Note that the only reason your allocation can fail is really a lack of available -- contiguous -- memory. This resource degrades over time if you do many allocations and frees, because the memory becomes fragmented.
For this reason try and limit the allocs and frees. Also you might want to test your user input so that the values are within reasonable limits. Allocating huge blocks of memory using cudaMallocHost will slow the system down, because this memory is pinned and cannot be swapped out to disk, potentially starving your system of available memory or even deadlocking it.

I edited my post trying to make it clear, I do many allocation then when one fails I try to free memory of the before ones, and those frees fails too.
